# Background color of content in PrimeNG Divider Component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a problem with changing background color of text inside of Divider supplied by PrimeNG.
Whole section got its background color by adding class to div container:
[div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rIxE.png)

But it does not apply to background of Text of Divider:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqv6P.png)

Here is my code to insert the Divider:
[divider code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLgF1.png)

Adding bg-grey-100 class to p-divider marker does not work. Putting p-divider into div container with bg-grey-100 class does not work. Putting Text into span container with bg-grey-100 class partially works, but there are white fields on sides of Text:
[span result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8ubj.png)

Thanks for help